# Pulling from an auto-updating Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

So I'm using xlrd to pull data from an Excel sheet. I get it open and it pulls the data perfectly fine.

My problem is the sheet updates automatically with data from another program. It is updating stock information using an rtd pull.

Has anyone ever figured out any way to pull data from a sheet like this that is up-to-date?

Comment: Where do you want to pull data?

Comment: I'm just pulling it into Python, to use it is a variable/etc

Comment: RTD is too complex. Xlrd is just as simple as a data reader, it will never support that.  2 ideas: pull data from RTD-server by python socket; write a excel-macro to export data every-1-minute (let excel do RTD job).

Answer (score 1):

Since all that xlrd can do is read a file, I'm assuming that the excel file is saved after each update.

If so, use `os.stat()` on the file before reading it with xlrd and save the results (or at least those of `os.stat().st_mtime`). Then periodically use `os.stat()` again, and check if the file modification time (`os.stat().st_mtime`) has changed, indicating that the file has been changed. If so, re-read the file with xlrd.